# Select Populating but not showing values (php/msqli)

Tags: php, database, forms, mysqli

So I'm working on a dropdown that shows users on my site and when I load the page I can tell it is connecting to the database and selecting the right table, column and everything because it's showing the right number of options but all the options are blank... what am I doing wrong?

```
<?php $users = $conn->query("SELECT username FROM users"); ?>

<label for="ref" class="ref">If you were referred to RDR PLEASE select your referrer's Username:</label>
<select name="referrer" style="width:150px">
        <option value="None"></option>
        <?php while($rows = $users->fetch_array())
        {
                $user = $rows['$users'];
                echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
        } ?> </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your column name seems "username" from your sql query.

```
        <?php while($rows = $users->fetch_array())
        {
                $user = $rows['username'];
                echo "<option value='$user'>$user</option>";
        } ?> </select>
```

Comment: you were right but without the $...
``` 
$user = $rows['username'];
```

Comment: thank you for correcting that. Please accept answer as solution or vote if it helped you :)

Comment: new to the site so i didn't know to do that... done now :)